# difference between Spark parallel range versus submit splitted range using multi-thread?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing

Suppose there are 10k simple direct tasks to be done,  which is better ?

```
//method 1
spark.parallize(range(1,10k)).map(taskDone)

//method 2
range(1, 10k).stream().parallel().map(spark.rdd(x).collect() /*do one using spark*/)
```

are they equivalent? or which is preferred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *fundamentally* different.

### On the one hand

```
spark.parallize(range(1,10k)).map(taskDone)
```

This creates locally (on the driver node) one range object with 10k elements. This range is shipped to the executor nodes of the cluster (each receiveing N elements), and each worker applies the task to those N elements, while the driver (presumably - because here, a final step is needed to actually make the computation start) waits for the results to come back.

More specifically :

```
spark.parallize(range(1,10k))
```

Is code that runs, single threadadly on the driver. What it does is create a range, and ask spark to split it (ship it to executor nodes)

And then

```
.map(taskDone)
```

Ships the code inside of `taskDone` to the executors so that the task is applied concurrently to the extent permitted by the cluster once the computation is triggered.

### On the other hand...

```
range(1, 10k).stream().parallel().map(spark.rdd(x).collect() /*do one using spark*/)
```

This creates a range on the driver, with 10k elements. Each of the 10k element is then parallely (the level of parallelism being that of a single machine, the driver node, which has nothing to do with the cluster) assigned to a RDD (that contains a single element), and (presumably) creates 10k tasks for the cluster, each working on a single element.

This second way of doing things will almost surely be vastly inefficient. Spark is designed to handle (very) large collections distributedly, using a programming model that make it looks like it is processed locally. That is your first code sample.

Your second code works the other way around : it creates on a single "computer" (the master node) a large number of very small collections, which defeats the purpose : there is no use of shipping a collection of a single element to a computing cluster !

More specifically:

```
range(1, 10k).stream().parallel().map(spark.rdd(x)
```

This is code that runs, serially, on a single computer, the driver. It creates a range, splits it (parellely) in individual (size = 1) elements, and turns each of these single elements to a RDD (a spark distributed collection) of this single element.

The level of parallelism that is achieved is that of the driver node. What is parallelized is the **creation of RDDs**, not the **execution of the work to be done on the elements**

Then :

```
.collect()
```

You ask for each RDD to be executed and collected back. To the extent that the sparkSession is thread safe and concurrent, those trivially small (1 item) RDDs are processed and sent back.

You are therefore limiting your parallelism to that of your driver node (which usually is not that big) instead of using the parallelism of the cluster (which can be enormous).

Do it the first way.

Comment: what if each of the task is realtively standalone?say IO intensive, does that make scenario two better?

Comment: Not really. Note that there might be some workflow, or some corner case, where solution 2 works. But, if the sparkSession is a factory, then solution 1 is : shipping a truck load of supplies and waiting for the result. Solution 2 is sending 10 guys with one item of supply each to the dock, having them wait for the factory to process this one item, then going back to fetch another single item. Factories don't work that way.